# Uncaught ReferenceError: ... onblur

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm getting an '**Uncaught ReferenceError chkBirthday is not defined onblur**' when I run my page in Chrome.

My script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).on("blur", "input[name=Birthdate]",
   function chkBirthday() {
      $("#Birthdate").datepicker({
         onSelect: function (dateText) {
            alert("dateText");
         }
      });
   });
</script>
```

My helper that calls this is:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(c => Model.Birthdate, new { @class = "datepicker",
                                maxlength = 10, @onBlur = "chkBirthday"})%>
```

What I'm trying to do here is get the value of **JQuery UI datepicker**.  The rest of my script (not shown here) essentially checks the date if entered manually and displays an error if this is blank.  This works despite getting the **Uncaught ReferenceError**.  I've tried changing **onBlur** to **unblur** so it's not that.

Using **Chrome's dev tools**, it shows the helper translates the id as '**Birthdate**' which should reference `$("#Birthdate")`, correct?  I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(c => Model.Birthdate, new { maxlength = 10 })%>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#Birthdate").bind('change blur', function () { 
       alert($(this).val());
   });
});
</script>
```